# getting the error "packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: 'None'" while executing the exe created by pyinstaller in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Using the following csv file [csv file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miura/NEUBIAS_AnalystSchool2020/master/Arianne/Dataset/grant_complete.csv)

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# import xarray as xr


import holoviews as hv
import colorcet as cc

df = pd.read_csv('./grant.csv')
print(df.head())
df_2012 = df.loc[df['year']==2012, :].copy()

hv.Points(
    data=df_2012,
    kdims=['beak length (mm)', 'beak depth (mm)'],
    vdims=['species'],
)
```

after using the following command for creating the exe , I could able to get the exe file inside

**`pyinstaller grant.py`**

ls dist/grant/**grant**

while running the this exe **./grant** I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grant.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "holoviews/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "holoviews/util/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "holoviews/core/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "holoviews/core/boundingregion.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "holoviews/core/util.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "packaging/version.py", line 266, in __init__
packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: 'None'
[1396395] Failed to execute script 'grant' due to unhandled exception!
```

Please help on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to use the `--collect-all` flag on the package `param` inside of your pyinstaller command.

for example:

```
pyinstaller -F --collect-all param grant.py
```

Or you can leave out the `-F`  if you don't want it compiled to a single file.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for quick help ,  it's working after using the flag appropriately.

Comment: is there any way so that we only build the exe and which running the exe it will take the dependencies from python path.                                                                                                                             I do not want to include the holoviews and pandas in to the exe as my exe size will increase rather at run time I can tell my exe from where to pick the above libs

Comment: @DebashishSamantaray You can, but it would kind of defeat the purpose since it would no longer be portable.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to do it ?                                                                                     b'se my exe size is growing large, I am using the  pyinstaller --exclude-module 'holoviews' grant.py though exe is getting created still unable to run it after importing the payhthon path where the holoviews is installed say : "/home/debashish/debvenv/bin/holoviews"

Comment: **[debashish~/test]$  dist/grant/grant**  
   Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "grant.py", line 7, in <module>  
    import holoviews as hv  
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'holoviews'  

**[debashish~/test]$ python grant.py**  
    band  beak depth (mm)  beak length (mm) species  year  
    0  20123             8.05              9.25  fortis  1973  
     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  
 Though using python grant.py is working fine , it's strange why .exe file is not getting the particular module

Comment: @DebashishSamantaray  Open a new SO question with all of this information and a thorough description of the problem and either I or someone else will be able to help you with it.

Comment: Dear @Alexader please find the link to the new question, I have tried to explain the whole scenario to my best.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76112350/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-holoviews-while-running-the-python-execut