# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'holoviews' while running the python executable created by pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# import xarray as xr


import holoviews as hv
import colorcet as cc

df = pd.read_csv('./grant.csv')
print(df.head())
df_2012 = df.loc[df['year']==2012, :].copy()

hv.Points(
    data=df_2012,
    kdims=['beak length (mm)', 'beak depth (mm)'],
    vdims=['species'],
)
```

using the following csv file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miura/NEUBIAS_AnalystSchool2020/master/Arianne/Dataset/grant_complete.csv

To run the above python file I have created a virtual env using python venv , where I have installed all my dependent libraray.

```
[debvenv] [debashish-rh8] cd debvenv 
bin/                etc/                include/            lib/                lib64@              pip-selfcheck.json  pyvenv.cfg          share/
```

in some other terminal say other directory I have the python file which needs to be run

```
[debashish-rh8] cd test 
grant.csv grant.py
```

by providing the path of the bin of venv which I have already created I could able to run the python file.

```
setenv PATH /home/debashish/debvenv/bin:$PATH
```

```
#python grant.py  

  band  beak depth (mm)  beak length (mm) species  year
0  20123             8.05              9.25  fortis  1973
1  20126            10.45             11.35  fortis  1973
2  20128             9.55             10.15  fortis  1973
3  20129             8.75              9.95  fortis  1973
4  20133            10.15             11.55  fortis  1973
```

Then I tried to create a executable for the  **grant.py**  using the following command

**pyinstaller -F --collect-all param grant.py**

> which creates a executable that I can run from anywhere from my machine as all the dependencies are embedded inside exe **self suffice exe** which increases the **size of exe which is my concern.**

To avoid that I have created the exe through following command

**pyinstaller --exclude-module 'holoviews' grant.py** which creates the exe excluding the holoview ,

while running the exe it's showing following error:

```
[debashish-rh8-~/test] ls
build dist grant.py grant.csv...

[debashish-rh8~/test]dist/grant/grant

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grant.py", line 7, in <module>
    import holoviews as hv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'holoviews'
[3045651] Failed to execute script 'grant' due to unhandled exception!

[debashish-rh8~/test$ which holoviews
/home/debashish/debvenv/bin/holoviews -> indicates holoviews module is already there 

[debashish-rh8~/test$ which python
/home/debashish/debvenv/bin/python
```

```
Though the running the python file works fine
[debashish-rh8~/test]python grant.py 
    band  beak depth (mm)  beak length (mm) species  year
0  20123             8.05              9.25  fortis  1973
1  20126            10.45             11.35  fortis  1973
2  20128             9.55             10.15  fortis  1973
3  20129             8.75              9.95  fortis  1973
4  20133            10.15             11.55  fortis  1973
```

I do not want to embed all the libraries to my exe let the exe pick the dependencies from the venv.

Would anyone please help me how to achieve this or somewhere I am doing wrong to exclude the libraries while using pyinstaller ?